# Which of the two sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which sentence is correct when each of x and y has made one defamatory statement?

1. ...whether the statement made by x and y are defamatory.
2. ...whether the statements made by x and y are defamatory.

Comment: If x said one thing defamatory in x's own statement and y said something else defamatory in y's own statement, then you would have to separate statements and would use: "whether the statements made by x and y are defamatory" They both can't say the exact statement, which would make it one statement, unless they did, then you would use the other clause "whether the statement made by x and y IS defamatory"

Comment: Sorry to ask another question, but would the same rule apply if i use "or" instead of "and"? As in: "whether the statements made by x OR y are defamatory"

Comment: You are using a plural verb (are), so the noun should also be plural.

Comment: As in: "whether the statements made by x OR y are defamatory" And = added to = x and y / Or = either = x or y / Again, if each made their own separate individual statements, then: "whether the statement made by x OR y is defamatory" [whether the statement made by either x or y is defamatory] / for example: Whether the book written by Joyce or Bill is truthful doesn’t mean they can’t be questioned. / The rule is using “or” makes the subject closet to the verb “is” the determiner of the verb’s number and since “y” is singular, the you are talking about y’s statement, thus statement  = singular

Comment: CORRECTION: Whether the book written by Joyce or Bill is truthful doesn’t mean *it* can’t be questioned.

Answer (score 1):

If X and Y **jointly** made **one** statement, it's "*statement is* defamatory". If they **each** made at least one statement of their own, it's "*statements are* defamatory."

The verb matches the subject, and the subject indicates the number of statements. Here, you have two separate statements, so you need *statements* and its matching verb *are*.

If you use *or* then you still have more than one statement ("statements are defamatory") but you are no longer specific about who made each of the statements. X could have made none, one or more; Y could have made none, one or more; all we know is that you have two people and more than one statement.

Comment: I don't think ELL would happily accept this question.

Comment: This answer is complete and correct. Why was it downvoted?